# Swift using Alamofire to make a http request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I got a problem in using Alamofire recently.

Here is my code
LoginViewController.swift

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

let baseApi = BaseApi()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let dict = ["name":name.text,"email":email.text, 
        "password":password.text]
    print("api succeed1")
    let result = baseApi.login(paras: dict as! [String : String])
    print("api succeed2")
    if result[0]["status"].string == "success" {
        print("api succeed3")
        present( UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: 
        nil).instantiateViewController
        (withIdentifier:"TabBarController") 
        as! TabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

BaseApi.swift

```
class BaseApi{

func login(paras : [String:String]) -> JSON {
    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login")
    let result = baseApi(url: url!,paras: paras)
    print("BaseApi3333")
    return result
}

func baseApi(url : URL,paras : [String:String]) -> JSON {

    var json:JSON = []

    let toke = getToken()

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "name": paras["name"]!,
        "email": paras["email"]!,
        "password": paras["password"]!
    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic "+toke,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            json = JSON(value)
            print("baseAp2222")
            print(json)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
    print("baseApi111")
    print(json)
    return json
}
}
```

Here is the log

```
api succeed1
baseApi111
[

]
BaseApi3333
api succeed2
baseAp2222
{
  "status_code" : 200,
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "token" : "xxxx"
  }
}
```

My question is why print(baseApi111) come out before print("baseAp2222"),I need to return json,but looks like the excute orders are not right,so the return json is nil,how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use callback closures to make a return call , you can not return data like this from api calls .

Let me give you an example - following method is making call to api using almofire -

```
func fetchDataFromWebService<T: Mappable>(_ parameters: Dictionary<String , AnyObject>, closure:@escaping (_ response: T) -> Void){
    let url = getWebServiceUrl()

    //        let url = NSURL(string: getWebServiceUrl)
    print("parameters = \(parameters)")

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200 || response.response?.statusCode == 201 {
                //   print(response.result.value)
                var user = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: response.result.value)
                //                    var user = Mapper<T>().map(response.result.value)
                if self.processSingleRecord() == true {

                    user = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: (response.result.value as! NSArray).object(at: 0))
                    //                        user = Mapper<T>().map(response.result.value?.objectAtIndex(0))
                }
                closure(user!)
                //                        print("user = ",user)
            }
            else if response.response?.statusCode == 0{
                //  print(self.DisplayNetworkAvailabilityMessage())
            }
            else  {
                if let _ = response.result.value as? Error {
                }
            }
            break

        case .failure(let error):
            debugPrint("getEvents error: \(error)")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            break

        }
    }

}
```

Now here is call to this method -

```
let anotherWebServiceHandler = DeviceTokenDataHandler.init()        anotherWebServiceHandler.fetchDataFromWebService(["":""], closure: { (response:SignUpResponse) -> Void in

    })
```

You need to understand [sequential code execution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/what-is-sequential-code-execution/144483) - and [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: Sounds like you are right,I am a new coder here,so could you please give me a simple example?

Comment: I just edited the answer , you need to attach a call back closures to your method that will be executed when your api will return something ..

Comment: Thanks man,I believe your answer is right,but I am trying to understand it..Looks like there are many things I need to know..